# jquery ui sortable table columns with fixed rows issues

Tags: jquery

There is a jquery ui sortable widget [extension](http://dbrink.github.com/sorttable/examples.html) which makes table columns sortable.
According to examples page it is possible to specify row as undruggable.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#ex7').sorttable({
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        helperCells: ':not(.footerrow td)'
    }).disableSelection();
    });​
```

I want to set several colspanned rows such way. 
But there are several issues occur when i set fixed rows in the middle of the table.
First - fixed rows is not showed as dragged during drag&drop, second - after several movements table becomes broken.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NyQPD/6/)

Is there any way to correct it?

**UPDATE:**

found workaround using absolute positioned div with width=table width, but actually i don't like it

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NyQPD/10/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you set the first cell of your static row to a `colspan` of 4.

When you move that column to the second position the cell with the `colspan` is shifted into second position.

Now you end up with the second column sontaining the cell with the `colspan` of 4 which off-sets everything.
I would try and avoid `colspans` in cells if you wish to move around columns.

You can fix this by simply adding empty cells instead of using a `colspan`.

Replace this:

```
<tr class="footerrow"><td colspan="4">unsortable  colspan row</td></tr>
```

with this:

```
<tr class="footerrow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

#### [DEMO - v1](http://jsfiddle.net/NyQPD/7/) - Using individual empty cells instead of colspan

In addition I would probably add some styles to hide the column borders for that row.

**Edit**

I played around a little longer with this and was able to come up with another alternative. Mind you it is not as smooth as yours and could be seen more `hacky` as well.

I looked at the `start` and `stop` callbacks of the sortable extension and wondered if one could add 4 cells at `start` and replace them again at `stop`.

When using `start` you will see 4 cells during sorting, which I didn't like as much as I thought that you want to see the footers during the drag-drop action.

The I noticed that when `stop` executes it executes prior to the actual sorting being applied, making `start` for our purpose redundant.

This means at `stop` we can replace the single cell with 4, let it sort, add a small time-delay using `window.setTimeout` which then after a small delay replaces the 4 cells again with the 1 cell. That also means the footer stays intact during drag-drop.

#### [DEMO - v2](http://jsfiddle.net/NyQPD/14/) - Using stop to re-draw footers before and after sorting

That seems to work but as I said it is not as smooth as yours as mine is redrawn and causes a little flicker. Also I'm not certain if 100 milliseconds will be enough on the `setTimout` call when you got a huge table.

Either way, I had fun working with this. I hope though this will give you at least some more ideas to play around with.

#### The code from the DEMO v2

> **HTML**
>   note I added a attribute `data-title` to the `tr` storing the title text to be able to 
>   dynamically add them. See the footer-row HTML below, all other HTML stay the same.

```
<tr class="footerrow" data-title="Additional Features"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

> **Script**
>   Added start callback. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
$(function() {
    $specialRows = $("#ex7 tr.footerrow");

    $('#ex7').sorttable({
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        helperCells: ':not(.footerrow td)',
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            // This replaces the 1 cell with 4 and executes before the sorting actually occurs.
            buildFooterTemplates();

            // Adding a small timeout we rever to the single cell with colspan 4
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                buildFooterRows();
            }, 100);
        }
    }).disableSelection();

    var buildFooterTemplate = function(title) {
        return '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>';
    };

    var buildFooterRow = function(title) {
        return '<td colspan="4" align=center>' + title + '</td>';
    };

    var buildFooterTemplates = function() {
        $specialRows.each(function() {
            var $row = $(this);
            var title = $row.attr("data-title");

            $row.empty().append(buildFooterTemplate());
        });
    };


    var buildFooterRows = function() {
        $specialRows.each(function() {
            var $row = $(this);
            var title = $row.attr("data-title");

            $row.empty().append(buildFooterRow(title));
        });
    };

    buildFooterRows();
});​
```

Comment: Hi Francois, thanks for reply. Yes it's clear that using row without colspan should avoid such type of a problems. But i need to create named groups of cell values. That is why row with individual cells instead of colspan row are not suitable in my case.

Comment: @user947668: I'm not sure what you mean by named group but you can always apply data attributes or classes to your `td` or `tr` elements for logical grouping if that is something that would suit.

Comment: @user947668: I like your trick and it is smooth/seamless as well in the UI. Nice one. I had a little more fun with the extensions and added another way to deal with this, using the extension's `stop` callback. Though this might be even more hacky than yours and it is not as smooth but as I had fun working with this I thought I might as well post it for completeness. Maybe you find even a completely new way through all of this. If you do, post it please I would be very interested.